Running ng lint I get Cannot find module 'nx/src/devkit-exports'
During an upgrade from angular 17 to 18 I cannot run ng lint properly without getting this error:
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'nx/src/devkit-exports'
Require stack:
- node_modules/@nx/devkit/index.js
- node_modules/@angular-eslint/builder/dist/lint.impl.js
- node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
See "/private/var/folders/fm/cd_pjjks48114thy_txjwvs1tjjn_t/T/ng-QxlD1i/angular-errors.log" for further details.

but I am not using nx at all
